# Cmake add_executable called with incorrect number of arguments

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

I am trying to set up c++ development environment on Linux (openSuse) with this tutorial https://youtu.be/LKLuvoY6U0I?t=154

When I try to build CMake project I'm getting 
`add_executable called with incorrect number of arguments`

My CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5)

project (CppEnvTest)

set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Werror -std=c++17")
set (source_dir "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/")

file (GLOB source_files "${source_dir}/*.cpp")

add_executable (CppEnvTest ${source_files})
```

My build.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

cmake -G "CodeLite - Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
```

My terminal output:

```
/Dev/CppEnvTest/src> ./build.sh 
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (add_executable):
  add_executable called with incorrect number of arguments


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on @arrowd's answer, which is correct, you have a couple options for listing your source files. Your approach, `file(GLOB ...)`, will *only* look for source files matching `.cpp` in the **current** directory. If your project is structured such that you have nested directories within `${source_dir}`, you need the [recursive](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#glob-recurse) option instead:

```
file (GLOB_RECURSE source_files "${source_dir}/*.cpp")
```

This will search recursively finding all of the `.cpp` files in that directory **and** any nested directories.

You can also do a brute-force method using [`set`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html), which is the best option for CMake, by doing something like this:

```
set(source_files 
    ${source_dir}/mySrcs1/Class1.cpp
    ${source_dir}/mySrcs1/Class2.cpp
    ${source_dir}/mySrcs1/Class3.cpp
    ...
    ${source_dir}/mySrcs42/testClass1.cpp
    ${source_dir}/mySrcs42/testClass2.cpp
    ...
)
```

Comment: I used the brute-force way and it worked
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your `source_files` variable seems empty. Verify that by adding `message("source_files: ${source_files}")` somewhere in `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: I've done it and got:

`/Dev/CppEnvTest/src> ./build.sh 
source_files: 
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:12 (add_executable):
  add_executable called with incorrect number of arguments


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
`